# Connect to Outlook button not enabled on external list

Tags: external-content-type, outlook

I created an external content type connected to a SQL table and chose announcements as the office item type.

Answer (score 3):

You need to enable enterprise features on SharePoint. Do this in central administration->upgrade and migration->enable enterprise features. At least that enabled it for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try using SharePoint Designer to edit the Entity you mapped to an announcement.

In my experience SharePoint Designer reports more warnings than a BDC Model import.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of features that are not supported on an External list since the content is not stored in SharePoint.  It would make sense that the Connect to Outlook feature is one that would not be available.

Comment: I am following a tutorial on wrox book Sharepoint professioanl development, and the last point is to synchronize with outlook, so if it doesnt support it, then that would be a big error on the book.

Comment: Luis, double check the list you have created, it may be that it is missing a property or the wrong type to synchronise to Outlook.

Comment: the campaign id is mapped to custom property, the name of the campaign is mapped to subject, the start and end date are mapped to start and end date respectiveyl
the type is announcement. DOnt know what else should I check